# ¿Cómo puedo agregar un salto en el eje de las y para representar mejor el gráfico de barras en ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estoy trabajando con `phyloseq` y `gglot` para analizar la estructura de una comunidad, realice un `plot_bar` pero uno de mis grupos es más abundante y en el gráfico no se puede apreciar los otros grupos.

Este es mi código:

```
gpp <- plot_bar(glomorder, fill = "Order")
gpp + labs(y="Abundancia", x="Sitio") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2") + 
  theme(legend.position="right", 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white',colour = 'gray'), 
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = 'gray',linetype = 'dotted' ) ) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title = NULL))
```

Y este es el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy pensando en agregar un salto en el eje de las y para que se puedan observar mejor los otros grupos, alguna recomendación.

Comment: Agrega la etiqueta R ya que mucha gente la sigue y así van a ver mas fácil tu consulta.

Comment: ¿Has probado modificando la escala del eje y? con `+ scale_y_log10()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes algunas posibilidades que puedes explorar. Voy a usar un ejemplo básico en `ggplot` que entiendo es la base que usa `phyloseq`.

```
data <- data.frame(x=factor(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')), y=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 10000))
ggplot(data, aes(x, y, fill=x)) +
    geom_col()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La categoría `E` hace que se pierdan las barras del resto de las categorías. Lo primero que se me ocurre es:

#### 1. Modificar la escala a una logarítmica:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y, fill=x)) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_y_log10()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### 2. Usar `gridExtra`para dividir en dos gráficos con distinta escalas (zoom)

```
library(gridExtra)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y, fill=x)) +
    geom_col()

p1 <- p + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(100, 1000))
p2 <- p + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 99))
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 1)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### 3. Crear dos grupos a partir de un cierto `y` para facetarlos luego

```
data$grupo <- "(2) de 1 a 99"
data$new_y <- ifelse(data$y<100, data$y, 100)
new_rows <- data[data$y>=100,]
new_rows$new_y <- new_rows$y
new_rows$grupo <- "(1) de 100 a 10.000"
data <- rbind(data, new_rows)

ggplot(data, aes(x, new_y, fill=x)) +
    geom_col() +
    facet_wrap(~grupo, scales="free_y", ncol=1)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! las recomendaciones fueron muy buenas, finalmente hice un facet_wrap() por cada uno de los grupos

Answer (score 3):

No se puede. Por lo menos ggplot no lo permite.

Esto es principalmente porque suele ser dudoso insertar un corte en el eje, desde el punto de vista de la fiabilidad de los datos presentados.

Librerías como `plotrix` [permiten rotura de ejes](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plotrix/versions/3.7-4/topics/axis.break) pero al ser otro paquete las funciones típicas cambian.

Un mejor acercamiento con ggplot sería usar una escala logarítmica para el eje y (como te indican en los comentarios). Eso permite visualizar mejor las diferencias en un gráfico sin cortes.